# How to get the integers 35 and 50 in the output of this program ?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, inheritance, polymorphism

I am really very new in C++ programming and its been only a month i started learning Object Oriented Programming and i was learning this program of inheritance and I am not getting the output i wanted. What is wrong in this source code below.

```
  #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class enemy{
    private:
        int attackpower;
        public:
            void enemys(int x)
            {
                attackpower=x;
            }

    };

            class monster : public enemy
            {
                public:
                 enemy::enemys;

            };

            class ninja : public enemy
            {
                public:
                 enemy::enemys;
            };


int main()
{
    monster object1;
cout<<"You get points : - "<<endl;  object1.enemys( 35);

    ninja object2;
cout<<"You get points  : - "<<endl; object2.enemys( 50);

}
```

well the output I get is this :

output : 
You get points : - 
You get points : -

I am suppose to get the integers i mentioned after "You get points : - 35 " and "You get points - 50"

as per the program I am not getting the integers in output. WHat could be wrong?

I am new to programming so please kindly help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There's nowhere in your code that you output the integers. I'm not sure why you think any integers should be output.

Comment: Putting a call to `object.enemys()` on the same line as some output does not output it (not to mention that it returns void). To fix it, you'd first need a way to get the `attackpower` out of the object (right now you can only set it). Then you can output it by chaining the insertion operator: `cout<<"You get points : - "<<object1.functionThatReturnsAttackPower();<<endl;`. By the way, reconsider having a class inherit and contain another class. This will surely only serve to later confuse you.

Comment: I think the problem with your code is that although it has some inherited classes in it, it isn't making any **use** of inheritance. There is nothing there that you couldn't do without inheritance. Maybe that's why you are struggling with the concept.

Comment: This subject line is not going to be useful to anybody, unless there is somebody who also need to print 35 and 50, in which case why not just do `cout << 35 << endl << 50 << endl;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that makes (very slight) use of inheritance. Maybe you'll find it useful

```
  #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class enemy{
    private:
        int attackpower;
        public:
            enemy(int ap)
            {
                attackpower = ap;
            }
            int get_attackpower()
            {
                return attackpower;
            }

    };

        class monster : public enemy
        {
        public:
            monster() : enemy(35)
            {
            }
        };

        class ninja : public enemy
        {
        public:
            ninja() : enemy(50)
            {
            }
        };


int main()
{
    monster object1;
    cout<<"You get points : - " << object1.get_attackpower() << endl;

    ninja object2;
    cout<<"You get points  : - "<< object2.get_attackpower() << endl;

}
```

output is

```
You get points : - 35
You get points  : - 50
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1534269/john
Thanks a lot for your answer. I figured out what u did .. i think u use the return method and accessed the variable and then used that function get_attackpower() with the objects right? pls correct me if i am wrong.
Thanks a lot btw can u please tell me more details about "monster() : enemy(35)
            {
            }
and 
ninja() : enemy(50)
            {
            }

please tell me what u actually did here.

Comment: That's right. This code `monster() : enemy(35) { }` is the monster constructor, it constructs the monster by first creating an enemy object with attackpower 35. Because monster inherits from enemy every time you create a monster object you also create an enemy object. ninja is the same, both inherit from enemy, so enemy is just for things that ninja and monster share, like havving an attackpower (even though it's not the same attackpower).

Comment: wow.. that is so great. I think its time for me to learn about constructors again and do some programs on it until i learn it.

Thanks once again .